# Unwanted row is returned

Tags: mysql

I am trying to filter my products according to the category and the id of the designer, however, i get a wrong category returned which is not connected to the specific designer, this is what i tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `items` 
WHERE category =  'dress1'
OR category =  'dress2'
or category = 'skirt'
OR designerID =  '1'
OR designerID =  '2'
```

now i get an output of dress1, dress 2, AND skirt, however neither of the designer id's are connected to the 'skirt' category, why is it still returned?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your requirements, it sounds like you want the results to have `category`  `dress1`, `dress2`, or `skirt`, but only if they have `designerID` of `1` or `2`.

If so You need an `AND` clause there, I would make your `WHERE` clause look like this:

```
WHERE (category =  'dress1'
OR category =  'dress2'
OR category = 'skirt')
AND (designerID =  '1'
OR designerID =  '2')
```

Comment: Yes, the requirements are correct, however this clause still returns skirt, although it is definitely neither id 1 or 2? =(

Comment: @user2209644 Sorry, for clarification, my query returns a row with `skirt`, where the id is NOT `1` or `2`? Could you tell me what the id for `skirt` is?

Comment: yes, the id of skirt is 3 to be exact, dress1 and dress2 is id 1 and 2 respectively

Comment: oops, looks like i have messed up with the brackets, it all works now, thank you

Comment: @user2209644 Oh, ok, awesome!

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  items
WHERE
  category in ('dress1','dress2','skirt')
  and designerID in ('1','2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : if you want the designers 1 and 2 and all three dres type

```
SELECT * FROM  `items` WHERE category in('dress1','dress2','skirt') OR designerID in('1','2');
```

If you wanted the combination of designer and dres put and AND instead of OR